# Log4j - Force log message parameters

Tags: java, log4j

I am trying to force the detail within log4j messages as opposed to just a string. Ultimately I would like to have something like:

logger.info("component", "error code", " error message");

I may even use an enum for the component.

I would then expect the message to appear in the log as "time - component - code - message"

Any ideas?

Comment: Usually with log4j, name of class where exception is catched is logged. And error code is merged within message. You can grep error code later on, just invent your format to differentiate between code and text of message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A very trivial solution (for this special case):

```
logger.info(
      String.format("%s - %s - %s", "component", "error code", "error message"));
```

or in an improved version:

```
logger.info(createMessage("component", "error code", "error message"));
```

with

```
public static String createMessage(
                 String component, String errorCode, String errorMessage) {
   return String.format("%s - %s - %s", 
                 "component", "error code", "error message");
}
```

---

For a more general solution, consider wrapping the original Logger class into a custom logger class and implement an `info` method that takes the three arguments and delegates to `internalLogger.info(String message)` with the new message based on the input.

Comment: Thanks everyone Andreas had the solution that we used.